# Python only sends output interactvely

Tags: bash, python-2.7

When I run my python script (content irrelevant for this question, just uses `print` a couple of times) interactively, it sends the output straight away.

When I use it in a pipe to `tee` or in an output redirection (`./script.py > script.log`) there is no output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Answered my own question below, it turned out to be a buffering issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're encountering output buffering, where it's waiting to get a certain number of bytes before it flushes.  You can look at the `unbuffer` command if that is undesirable for you.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, Python detects whether or not you are using a tty, and increases its buffering when you are not. Several options on how to disable this can be viewed at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering).